# Scraping proxies from proxies.txt file python

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I have this code to send requests using proxies if they are in the file, however, the script is not using the proxies but my local IP:

```
# open proxy file and get the number of proxies and the proxies as a list
f = open('proxies.txt', 'r')
proxy_str = f.read()
line_count = sum(1 for line in f)
proxy_list = proxy_str.replace('\n', ', ').split(', ')

if line_count > 0:
    try:
        proxy_index = random.randint(0, len(proxy_list) - 1)
        proxies = {'http://': proxy_list[proxy_index],
                   'https://': proxy_list[proxy_index]}
        response1 = requests.get(product_link, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
    except:
        print("Proxy error")
        pass
else:
    response1 = requests.get(product_link, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
proxies = {
    'http:': proxy_list[proxy_index],
    'https:': proxy_list[proxy_index]
}
```

Comment: I still have the same problem, it still uses the local IP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet from the documentation -- it works for me like a charm. Note the keys of the `proxies` dictionary.

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies

```
proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',   # your proxies here
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',  # your proxies here
}

requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```